# Laravel from artisan to XAMPP (apache)

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp

I need to switch from localhost running with Artisan to server side running with XAMPP (apache). When copying my project in the htdocs file and running all the lay out is removed. What did I forget? I'm using Laravel 5.5

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **all the lay out is removed**?

Comment: he can't load the js or css files.. see image original question (edited)

Comment: Can you check in the network tab and tell me the full url where the app is looking for the static files?